# How to reshape a numpy matrix from 2D to 3D column-wise?

Tags: python, matrix, 3d, 2d, reshape

I do not understand the reshape function in `numpy` in Python. I have got the following problem:

I want to reshape the `(6, 2)` array

```py
A = np.c_[np.arange(1, 7), np.arange(6, 12)]
```

Which is

```py
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4,  9],
       [ 5, 10],
       [ 6, 11]])
```

Into a `(2, 3, 2)` array like

```py
array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]])
```

I have tried

```py
np.reshape(A, (2, 3, 2), order='F')
```

But the result was not what I am looking for. Instead, it was:

```py
array([[[ 1,  6],
        [ 3,  8],
        [ 5, 10]],

       [[ 2,  7],
        [ 4,  9],
        [ 6, 11]]])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. The shape you want is actually `(2, 2, 3)`, not `(2, 3, 2)`.
2. `order="F"` doesn't do what you think it does. What you actually want is to transpose the array using `A.T`.

Also, you can use `A.reshape(...)` instead of `np.reshape(A, ...)`.

Here is the code:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.c_[np.arange(1,7), np.arange(6,12)]
print(A)
print("\n->\n")
print(A.T.reshape((2, 2, 3)))
```

Which gives:

```py
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4,  9],
       [ 5, 10],
       [ 6, 11]])

->

array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]])
```

### Explanation of `order="F"` vs. `.T`

Try `A.ravel(order="F")` to see what the elements of the array are in the `"F"` order. You will get:

```py
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  7],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4,  9],
       [ 5, 10],
       [ 6, 11]])

->

array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

Now if you apply a normal `order` after this, you get your expected result:

```py
A.ravel(order="F").reshape((2, 2, 3)) -> 

array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]])
```

The problem is, **`order="F"` also affects how the ravelled elements are added back into the array**. Not only are the elements taken out column-wise, they are added back in column-wise as well. So:

```py
[[[], []], [[], []]] -> 
[[[1], []], [[], []]] -> 
[[[1], []], [[2], []]] -> 
[[[1], [3]], [[2], []]] -> 
[[[1], [3]], [[2], [4]]] -> 
[[[1, 5], [3]], [[2], [4]]] -> 
[[[1, 5], [3]], [[2, 6], [4]]] -> 
[[[1, 5], [3, 7]], [[2, 6], [4]]] -> 
[[[1, 5], [3, 6]], [[2, 6], [4, 7]]] -> 
[[[1, 5, 8], [3, 6]], [[2, 6], [4, 7]]] -> 
[[[1, 5, 8], [3, 6]], [[2, 6, 9], [4, 7]]] -> 
[[[1, 5, 8], [3, 6, 10]], [[2, 6, 9], [4, 7]]] -> 
[[[1, 5, 8], [3, 6, 10]], [[2, 6, 9], [4, 7, 11]]]
```

**Not**:

```py
[[[1], []], [[], []]] -> 
[[[1, 2], []], [[], []]] -> 
[[[1, 2, 3], []], [[], []]] -> 
[[[1, 2, 3], [4]], [[], []]] -> 
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]], [[], []]] -> 
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[], []]] -> 
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[6], []]] -> 
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[6, 7], []]] -> 
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[6, 7, 8], []]] -> 
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[6, 7, 8], [9]]] -> 
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[6, 7, 8], [9, 10]]] -> 
[[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]], [[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]]
```

Therefore, you end up with an odd result. If you just want to take the elements out with `order="F"` but not add them back in that way, transposing the array will have the same effect.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If I want to transpose now the matrices A[0, :, :] and A[1,: ,:]?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. What would be your expected result?

Comment: The expected result is np.array([[[1,3,5],[2,4,6]],[[6, 8, 10],[7, 9, 11]]])

Comment: To get this result, you want to transpose the array and then use `order="F"` as well. So, `A.T.reshape((2, 2, 3), order="F")`